# Synonymize [magic-the-gathering-arena] into [mtg-arena]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

We have currently two tags about Magic: The Gathering Arena:

[mtg-arena](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-arena), 8 questions

[magic-the-gathering-arena](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-the-gathering-arena), 9 questions

Obviously, these tags are duplicates; can somebody with ♦ powers merge/synonymize them? Since all 'specialized' Magic tags start with `mtg-` I prefer the former.

I have also submitted an edit to the excerpt stating that it should only be used for questions about situations *specific* to Arena, not just because they happened during an Arena game.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have set up the requested synonym. [mtg-arena](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-arena) is now the canonical tag for this topic.